# Wrong value for the derivative of the solution of an ODE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, derivative

Trying to solve a Cauchy problem for a nonlinear ODE with the classical Runge-Kutta method described in [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54611-solving-odes-in-matlab) (see, `ode4`). After running this part

```
q = 10;
T = 5;
N = @(g1, g2) g1^2 + sin(g2);

t = linspace(0, T, q);
GCC = nonlinearGreenCC(N, 1, T);
di = diff(GCC);
```

I evaluate `GCC(1)` and `di(1)`. While `GCC(1) = 0` as expected, `di(1) = 1.6e-05`. Can't understand why, because the Cauchy condition on the first derivative is 1. How to fix the inaccuracy/mistake? Any help is highly appreciated.

The function `nonlinearGreenCC` is as follows:

```
function G = nonlinearGreenCC(N, a0, T)

h = .0001;
eqGreen = @(t, g)[g(2); - N(g(1), g(2))];
Cc = [0, a0];
G = ode4(eqGreen, 0, h, T, Cc);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GCC` is an array of pairs of values, starting for a more exact integration with something like

```
[  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
[  9.99957927e-05,   9.99915855e-01],
[  1.99983171e-04,   9.99831715e-01],
[  2.99962136e-04,   9.99747579e-01],
[  3.99932687e-04,   9.99663448e-01],
```

for exact values, but your result using the `ode4` function starts with something like

```
 0                         1
 1.66652642851402e-05      1.00001666526429
-1.40231141152723e-05      0.999985976885885
 1.66638620438405e-05      1.00001666386204
-1.40217119017434e-05      0.999985978288098
```

It does not contain the sampling of the time interval, indeed on the level that you call `diff`, the value of `h` is unknown. There is no way that `diff` can compute the difference quotients that you seem to expect. If you read the documentation you should find that it computes just the differences. And the first difference returns just the first value `1.66652642851402e-05`.

---

The direct error that causes the `ode4` algorithm to produce strange results is that `eqGreen` produces column vectors where it should return row vectors. As the initial value is a row vector, the result of adding row and column vectors in `ode4` produces a 2x2 matrix that is added as 2 rows to the result with confusing consequences. Having both row vectors puts the results into one row with alternating value and derivative.  Change to

```
eqGreen = @(t, g)[g(2), - N(g(1), g(2))];
Cc = [0, a0];
```

and the result is

```
GCC(1:5,:) =

                     0                     1
  9.99957927208439e-05     0.999915855174488
  0.000199983171186392     0.999831714893813
  0.000299962135851046     0.999747579156327
  0.000399932687169042     0.999663447960381

di(1:5,:)=

  9.99957927208439e-05  -8.41448255122224e-05
  9.99873784655483e-05  -8.41402806746050e-05
  9.99789646646540e-05  -8.41357374861129e-05
  9.99705513179961e-05  -8.41311959463020e-05
  9.99621384254097e-05  -8.41266560547282e-05
```

If you scale the last by dividing by `h=1e-4` you get the expected results.

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you for a nice answer. Now, what confuses me is why `GCC` has two columns and what does its second column mean? Another thing is that when define
`eps = .0001;`
`eqGreen = @(t, g)[g(2), - N(g(1), g(2)) + a0 * 1/(eps * pi) * exp( -t^2/eps^2)];`
and
`Cc = [0, 0];`
then `di(1)  = 0.1357`. However, `di(1)` is nothing else but the first derivative of the solution evaluated at `t = 0`, right? Then, it should return `0`. This is also unclear.

Comment: `GCC` has two columns as the first-order system for an order 2 ODE has a two-dimensional state space. That's why your `eqGreen` function returns a vector with two components. The first component of the state vector `g` is the function value, the second the first derivative. The return value has the derivative order increased by one.

Comment: Your modified system is stiff. Regardless of if it has the correct theoretical behavior, to correctly capture the pulse you need `h/eps << 1`, at the moment `h=eps=1e-4` which will certainly return not only quantitatively but also qualitatively wrong results. Try `eps=1e-2` with `h=1e-4`, this could be qualitatively correct.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, it is all clear now. I have returned to the initial system which is not stiff. I am just going to store the columns of `GCC` into two different vectors. Hope it will help to achieve my aim.

Comment: Better try `eps=1e-3` first. The Gaussian pulse has only `pi^0.5` in the denominator. And your integration only goes over half the pulse, thus correct to `...+ a0 * 2/(eps * pi^0.5) * exp( -t^2/eps^2)`. Then the derivative column goes close to `1` starting around `t=2e-3`.

Comment: Once I consider `Cc = [0, a0]`, it is not necessary to consider the Gaussian pulse. In fact, in my case, these systems are equivalent. Thank you very much for your kind advice